# Type 'typeof Questions' is not assignable to type 'typeof Model'

Tags: nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I am getting the error `Type 'typeof Questions' is not assignable to type 'typeof Model'.` while added the relationship in the model.

question.model.ts

```
import { Column, Table, PrimaryKey, Default, DataType, Model } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table({timestamps: true})
export class Questions extends Model<Questions> {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Default(DataType.UUIDV1)
    @Column(DataType.UUID)
    id: string;

    @Column
    question: string;

    @Column({ defaultValue: true })
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

options.model.ts

```
import { Column, Table, PrimaryKey, Default, DataType, ForeignKey, HasOne, Model } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { Questions } from "./models/questions.model";

@Table({timestamps: true})
export class Options extends Model<Options> {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Default(DataType.UUIDV1)
    @Column(DataType.UUID)
    id: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => Questions)
    @Column
    questionsId: number;

    @HasOne(() => Questions)
    question: Questions;

    @Column({ defaultValue: false })
    isCorrectAns: boolean;
}
```

my user module

```
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Questions } from './models/questions.model';
import { Options } from './options.model';

@Module({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forFeature([Questions, Options])
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs on Nest's site, `Model` is supposed to come from `sequelize-typescript`. You're importing it from `sequelize/types`.

Comment: Updated the import from `sequelize-typescript`, but the issue still remains

Answer (score 8):

I've had this same issue. Could resolve this by removing the type constructor (`<Questions>`, `<Options>`).

In my case I had a QuestionsAttributes interface and had to change:

```
class TalentData extends Model<TalentData, TalentDataAttributes>
```

to:

```
class TalentData extends Model implements TalentDataAttributes
```

But this appears to be a sequelize-typescript error.

Answer (score 0):

Let say we have two tables Likes and Quotes, and we just want to reference the quote_id as foreign key in Likes table :
Define the foreign key like this

```
@ForeignKey(() => Quotes)
@Column
quote_id: number;  

@BelongsTo(() => Quotes, {onDelete: "cascade", foreignKey: "quote_id"})
quote: Quotes;
```

**Note - please import BelongsTo from sequelize-typescript instead sequelize/types**